# I can't get my loop with accumulator to work properly, throwing error Python

Tags: python, loops, iteration, accumulator

I am trying to make a program to have a user input course name, number, grade, and credit hours to calculate the GPA and Quality points. I believe all calculations are correct, but I am not certain because my loop is broken. I am trying to make a loop where the iteration (ittNum) is accumulated and compared to the user's input of how many classes were take. Basically I want to have the loop and and for my data to be returned for use in the total calculation once the user has input the number of classes they took.

This is my latest error message.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/FinalProgram1.py", line 40, in 
    ClassGPA()
  File "D:/Python/FinalProgram1.py", line 13, in ClassGPA
    ittNum = int('')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

````
#Ask user's input for total classes taken
classesTaken = int(input('How many classes did you take? '))

#set function to take inputs and do calculations, should return values
#to variables defined
def ClassGPA():
    courseNum = input('What was the course number? ')
    courseName = input('What was the name of the course? ')
    courseGrade = input('What was your letter grade? ')
    courseHour = int(input('How many credit hours was the course worth? '))
    ittNum = int('')
    if courseGrade == ('A'): numGrade = 4.00
    elif courseGrade == ('A-'): numGrade = 3.67
    elif courseGrade == ('B+'): numGrade = 3.33
    elif courseGrade == ('B'): numGrade = 3.00
    elif courseGrade == ('B-'): numGrade = 2.67
    elif courseGrade == ('C+'): numGrade = 2.33
    elif courseGrade == ('C'): numGrade = 2.00
    elif courseGrade == ('C-'): numGrade = 1.67
    elif courseGrade == ('D+'): numGrade = 1.33
    elif courseGrade == ('D'): numGrade = 1.00
    elif courseGrade == ('F'): numGrade = 0.00
    qualityPoints = (numGrade * courseHour)
    print('Course:', courseNum, ', Course Name:', courseName, ', Quality Points:',\
          qualityPoints, ', GPA:', numGrade)
    ittNum = ittNum + 1
    totalHour += courseHour
    totalQual += qualityPoints
    totalGPA += numGrade
#Set loop condition
    if ittNum <= classesTaken:
        ClassGPA()
    else:
        return totalHour
        return totalQual
        return totalGPA

ClassGPA()

GPA = (totalGPA / totalQual)
print('Your total Quality Points for the semester were ', sum(totalQual))
print('Your total GPA for the semester was ', GPA```
````

Comment: `ittNum = int('')` <------- should be `ittNum = 0`

Comment: won't this reset ittNum to 0 everytime? I just changed it and it runs a continuous loop now

Comment: I suggested that because you used this line  `ittNum = ittNum + 1`

Comment: okay, but it is still running a continuous loop

Comment: What's this `classesTaken`???

Comment: i will update my code, i guess i missed highlight that part before posting, I'm sorry.

Comment: it has been updated, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:
`ittNum = int('')`

You are trying to cast empty string to `int`, it cannot be done.

EDIT:

There are many more problems with this code.

1. This isn't a loop. Instead, this is an improper use of recursion.
2. Your variable `classesTaken` is never declared or initialized.
3. The values this function returns (if it ever does, see problem #2) are never assigned to anything.
4. You can only return once from a function. The two items returned after the first will never actually be returned.
5. It appears you're trying to use the return variables `totalGPA` and `totalQual`, this will never work this way, see problem #4.

Comment: I changed ittNum to = 0 but when I do this it runs a continuous loop. is it resetting to 0 everytime the loop runs?

Comment: okay, probably looks super basic and wrong because I am obviously trying to learn this stuff from scratch. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: @Dmart425 This isn't a true "loop," it's broken recursion. Also, you're never declaring/initializing `classesTaken`. When you call on your function (which is named as if it were a class (PEP8)), you don't do anything with the values returned. There are are lots of problems with the thought process behind the code you have written here. My answer here simply addresses the exception you're currently dealing with.

This code may be too far gone to "save."

Comment: @Dmart425 I can appreciate that you are learning this from scratch. I'd suggest you start small. Your code reflects a misunderstanding about how some basic fundamentals work. There are lots of free tutorials out there. I suggest this one, from microsoft: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFCNu1-Xdsw

Comment: @Dmart425 Also, following PEP8 styling, as close as you can, will help other python programmers understand your code more quickly. At a glance, the references to `ClassGPA()` look like your instantiating an instance of a class named `ClassGPA` because of your use of pascal casing.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: thanks Joshua. Man, this stuff is tough. I got it worked out, basically took it all out of the function and made it run line by line. I added a while (ittNum <= classesTaken):
    for i in range (1, classesTaken, +1): to make my loop work. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Dmart425 No problem. Keep at it. The beginning is the hardest part, understanding how to think like a computer. Once you get that down, the rest is just syntax and best practices. 

Also, I'd like to take this moment to address my use of the wrong "you're/your" in my last comment. I meant, "...look like you're instantiating an instance..." :)